# MongoDB Java use multiple filters and get last

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, bson, mongo-collection

In my collection the documents look like this:

[image]

I've managed to get the last inserted document by doing this:

```
collection.find().sort(new Document("date",-1)).first().getDate()
```

But now I need to get the last by date AND that has got a specific value for `functionalityName`. I'm stuck because I don't know how to modify it to take in consideration both filters. How do I do that?
I had a look at multiple filters in Mongo but since I'm not looking for a specific date but for the greater one (last one), I don't know how to specify that together with other filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want one filter and a sort, and the query would look like this:

```
collection.find(Filters.eq("functionalityName", "specificValue"))
          .sort(new Document("date",-1))
          .first()
          .getDate()
```

So the `sort` part stays as is but in the `find` part you add the filter.

You'll also need to import the Filters class:

```
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
```

---

Alternatively, you can import the `Filters` class statically for brevity, this is how [the examples in the official Filters documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/builders/filters/) are done, which you may want to check out if you need to add additional filters.

```
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;

// ...

collection.find(eq("functionalityName", "specificValue"))
      .sort(new Document("date",-1))
      .first()
      .getDate()
```

Answer (score 1):

The concatenation of `find`, `sort` and so on surely works, **but** only `find()` is actually performed on database side, it will return the result and then sort will be applied on it by your application.

If you want to create a query that executes all those operation database side you need a [pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). To do it you can use the [Aggregation Framework](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/aggregation/) of the java driver that let you do something like this

```
collection.aggregate(
      Arrays.asList(
              match(eq("functionalityName", "specificValue")),
              sort(descending("date")),
              project(fields(include("date")))
      )
)
```

[In the documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/builders/aggregation/) you can find all the stages that you can apply to your pipeline.